# Small fix to regex to get numbers sequence of a string

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get the numbers sequence from the below line.

```
<div data-cid="8558641" class="clsfd_list_row_group">
```

I am doing this withous any luck

```
preg_match_all('!<div data-cid="\/(.*?)\/" class="clsfd_list_row_group">!is', $str, $urls);
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Use XPath `//div[@class="clsfd_list_row_group"]/@data-cid`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if i wanted to use xpath, I would ask

Comment: Then why did you add `\/` if there are no slashes in your input string? https://regex101.com/r/jV5kL9/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew since i am not an experience coder, I am trying a lot of things to come up with a solution. So back to this now, can you help me whit this?

Answer (score 0):

try with:

```
<div data-cid="(.*?)" class="clsfd_list_row_group">
```

The `"\/(.*?)\/"` is looking for something more like `"(content)"` but tere is not braces in your example input.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily do it with an `xpath` query:

```
<?php

$data = <<<DATA
<div>
    <div data-cid="8558641" class="clsfd_list_row_group">
    <div data-cid="12345" class="clsfd_list_row_group">
    <div data-cid="123" class="clsfd_list_row_group">
</div>
DATA;


$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($data);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$cids = $xpath->query("//div[@class='clsfd_list_row_group']/@data-cid");
foreach ($cids as $cid) {
    echo $cid->nodeValue . "\n";
}
?>
```

This outputs `8558641`, `12345` and `123`, see [**a demo on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/L8OPj3).